# Alternative to using Glob in Ant FileSet dir attribute

Tags: ant

I found it hard to think of a good title for this question about *Ant filesets*.

Given the following code base structure:

```
modules/module1/test/src/java/com/fixture/UserRepositoryFixture.java
                              com/user/UserRepositoryTest.java
                              com/product/ProducServiceTest.java
modules/module2/test/src/java/com/something/XTest.java
                              com/another/YTest.java
```

and assuming I don't know beforehand what modules I have, how can I get a fileset (or filesets)
that return all my test classes for use within the `<batchtest/>` element of *Ant's Junit* task?

To rule out some options that might initially occur:

```
<fileset dir="modules/**/test/src/java" includes="**/*Test.java"/>
```

won't work because globs cannot be used to specifying the dir attribute.

while:

```
<fileset dir="modules/" includes="**/test/src/java/**/*Test.java"/>
```

returns all the required files, but in the format *module1/test/src/java/com/user/UserRepositoryTest.java* rather than the required *com/user/UserRepositoryTest.java*

Many thanks for any help.